# Running Tkinter in an Empty X Server

Tags: python, linux, tkinter

I have a python3 script that starts an X server by running `/usr/bin/X`, and then attempts to create a tkinter GUI. There is no window manager/desktop environment, just the blank X server.

However, when I run `tk.Tk()`, I get the following error:

`tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable`.

Comment: The X server only sets up the DISPLAY variable for shells running on the server.  You should be able to `export DISPLAY=:0`, or provide a `-display` command line parameter to your app (sometimes `--display`).

Comment: After trying all three of those, I still get the same error.

Comment: You should include your attempts in your question.

Comment: I don't know but it seems like there has to be created a `DISPLAY` environment variable maybe, tho that is what I just read from the error